add partial curved text to image with php imagick
I need to create an image with two lines of text using PHP imagick.
And the texts could be arched texts (curved) and I do not know how to do that.
I've managed to do it when both texts is normal or curved. But no idea if only one line of text needs to be curved / arched.
The following is my code:
<?php

$text1 = "TITLE HERE";
$text2 = "CUSTOM TEXT";

$textColor = "#ffb81c";

$text1_Pos = -40;
$text2_Pos = 40;

/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

$image->setResolution(300, 300);

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 200, new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

/* Add text color */
$draw->setFillColor($textColor);

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 57 );

/* Center text horizontally and vertically */
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

/* Create text 1 */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 0, $text1_Pos, 0, $text1);

/* Create text 2 */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 0, $text2_Pos, 0, $text2);

/* curved text */
$distort = array(120);
$image->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

$image->setImageMatte(true);
$image->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, $distort, false);

$image->trimImage(0);
$image->setImagePage($image->getimageWidth(), $image->getimageheight(), 0, 0);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

